# Declatring Struts 2 actions as annotation

Tags: java, struts2

I found a code for a class in the internet which using Spring and Struts2.

I only know how to declare actions in the XML file, so in that class I found this :

```
@ParentPackage(value = "showcase")
public class Languages extends ActionSupport {

   //deleted code

    @Action(value = "/languages", results = {
            @Result(type = "json", name = "success", params = {
                    "root", "languages"
            })})
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if (term != null && term.length() > 1) {
            ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String staticLanguage : staticLanguages) {
                if (StringUtils.contains(staticLanguage.toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase())) {
                    tmp.add(staticLanguage);
                }
            }
            languages = tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

//deleted code
```

So what is the equivalent for this using the XML file for Struts2?

Answer (score 0):

It's not equivalent, but is mapped to the same URL.

```xml
<package name="mypackage" namespace="/" extends="showcase">
  <action name="languages" class=com.struts.Languages">
    <result type="json">
       <param name="root">languages</param> 
    </result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Comment: This is XML configuration similar to that created by the convention plugin.